# Datetime is giving error while conversion

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, vb.net, visual-studio-2008

I have string in this formate : 19/8/1988

note: `String DateOfBirth=" 19/8/1988"`

When i use `Datetime.parse(DateOfBirth)` it gives me `invalid dateformat error`.

I am also unable to do it in `cdate(DateOfBirth)`

When i enters string in format mm/dd/yyyy i.e. `8/19/1988` then it does not gives me error.

Please help me to convert string into date in `mm/ddd/yyyy` format.

Comment: Try `TryParseExact` instead of `Parse` http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h9b85w22.aspx

Comment: `DateTime.ParseExact` Just search stackoverflow. You'll find millions of answers.

Comment: this was also giving me same error thats why i posted question

Comment: Note that `mm` means minutes not months, so when using `TryParseExact` write `MM`

Comment: @NavatKayAahe and you haven't posted that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Lowercase `mm` means minute instead of month, you need to use uppercase `M`(single character).

But you also need to use `ParseExact` with `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture`. Otherwise your current culture is used to get the date separator which is not necessarily `/`(in many countries it is `.`).

So this works with any culture:

```
DateTime.ParseExact("19/8/1988", "dd/M/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
```

<kbd>[**Demo**](http://ideone.com/YsQ8wg)</kbd>

[**The "/" Custom Format Specifier**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx#dateSeparator)

If you want to validate a given date-string you can use [`DateTime.TryParseExact`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/h9b85w22.aspx):

```
DateTime dt; 
if(DateTime.TryParseExact("19/8/1988", "dd/M/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out dt)) 
{
    // success, dt contains the correct date now
} 
else 
{
    // not a valid date 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Note that you have space before the date time, you need to remove that string before parse to DateTime using given format

```
var date = DateTime.ParseExact(DateOfBirth.Trim(), "d/M/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

if you have multiple date time formats then

```
var date = DateTime.ParseExact(DateOfBirth.Trim(), new string[] {"d/M/yyyy","M/d/yyyy"} , CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None);
```

Answer (score 1):

I know what cause for you error, system datetime default taking as US datetime format (mm/dd/yyyy) change this format in your system, goto `control panel --> regional and languages --> formats --> additional settings-->` date to change your desired format  this is manually solved your problem  or otherwise programmatically solved this way

```
DateTime.ParseExact("19/8/1988", "dd/M/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
```

Answer (score 1):

Net developer, here is a code its in vb and needs to be converted to C#

```
Dim time As DateTime = DateTime.Now
Dim format As String = "dd/MM/yyyy" 
' you can set format to both "dd/MM/yyyy" or "d/MM/yyyy"

MsgBox(time.ToString(format))
```

let me know if it helps.