# Date format conversion in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, datetime

How to convert 04/09/2013 8:09:10 PM to 09/04/2013 (MM-dd-yyyy). I tried to convert but it is taking 09 as date and 04 as month.

Please help

```
[HttpPost]
public string getdailynote(DateTime selectedDate)
//selectedDate gets date as 04/09/2013 8:09:10 PM
{
    string x = selectedDate.ToString("MM-dd-yyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
    string daily;
    DateTime dt = Convert.ToDateTime(x);
    //dt gets value as {09/04/2013 12:00:00 AM} but 09 as date and 04 as month
    Dnote.RealDate =dt;
    daily = _scheduler.GetDailyNote(Dnote);
    return daily;
}
```

Comment: Try `selectedDate.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy")`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3477735/convert-datetime-to-string-formatyyyymmdd

Comment: it duplicate question

Comment: @SenthilKumar kindly tag the question , That would be useful to learn more ,

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18461272/datetime-is-giving-error-while-conversion/18468634#18468634

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> it is taking 09 as date and 04 as month

Yes, because you have said it, change

```
"MM-dd-yyy"
```

to

```
"dd/MM/yyyy h:mm:ss tt"

DateTime.ParseExact("04/09/2013 8:09:10 PM","dd/MM/yyyy h:mm:ss tt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

[**Demo**](http://ideone.com/AVBKsr)

Now, if you want to convert it to string with this format `MM-dd-yyyy`:

```
string result = dt.ToString("MM-dd-yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Answer (score 2):

Use

```
DateTime.ParseExact(x , "MM-dd-yyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Answer (score 1):

When you convert *from* `DateTime` *to* `string` you use an overload of the instance method `ToString` where you can specify a format string, and that is fine.

But then when you convert in the other direction, you shouldn't use `Convert.ToDateTime` method. Instead use `DateTime.ParseExact` or `DateTime.TryParseExact` because with them you can again specify the format string you want (and the format provider (culture)).